# Cannot connect MySQL database from django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to connect my MySql server from Django application , but whenever I am running the command python manage.py runserver it showing the error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
 _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

But my settings.py connection string is like :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'django_personnel',       # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                   # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'personnel',          # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306',        # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

But I can easily connect the database from mysql shell :

```
 mysql -u root -ppersonnel django_personnel
```

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to make sure the USER and the PASSWORD are recognized by the DB and you can leave the HOST and the Port empty

Comment: @drabo2005 mysql -u root -ppersonnel django_personnel this is working fine from mysql command line. So I am pretty sure USER and PASSWORD are recognized by the DB.

Comment: It seems your django app is not using the database settings you posted. is there any local settings file overriding it?

Comment: leave empty the HOST ET PORT, and see what you get

Comment: Use Python's verbose mode (`python -v`) and figure out why Django isn't using your settings file.

Comment: Or just post the full settings file. There should be something there.

Comment: change the user other than ROOT and see what you will get

Comment: I tried with the same code in another machine working fine. Must be some issue with mysql instance .                                    But wondering mysql -u root -ppersonnel django_personnel this works fine in the same machine.

Comment: @DibyenduDutta Is there a local settings file? If there is one in your machine and not one in another machine, of course the code will work on the other machine.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your current user is not having permissions to connect to DB.
Re installing mysql will help
and also

```
'HOST': '', 

'PORT': '',
```

Leave these two fields empty

Comment: The db user in settings file is `root`, but the error message is for the db user `user`. It means that the specified settings is not being used. Reinstalling MySQL is not even related to this problem.

Comment: my bad 
what i meant was that the  localhost is not allowed to connect to DB
Mayb sm thing got screwed up when he was installing MySQL at the first place

Comment: localhost is not the issue. The username being used is `user` and it's not using any password for auth. Doesn't look like the db config is being used.

Comment: I tried with the same code in another machine working fine. Must be some issue with mysql instance .                                    But wondering mysql -u root -ppersonnel django_personnel this works fine in the same machine.

Comment: as i mentioned some issue with localhost to DB connectivity
you can easily screw it up while doing conf settings during mysql installation. Try re installing it after removing it completely( maybe    purge remove)

Comment: Sigh. There is not a single problem here that requires mysql reinstalling.